# Group Randomly Printed Strings into Groups of Two

Tags: javascript, random

I'm looking to group randomly printed strings into groups of two.

Here is my JavaScript code used to randomize the strings:

```
Array.prototype.shuffle= function(times){
    var i,j,t,l=this.length;
    while(times--){
        with(Math){
            i=floor(random()*l);j=floor(random()*l);
        }
        t=this[i];this[i]=this[j];this[j]=t;
    }
    return this;
}

var players=["Ben","Caleb","Alex","Ryder","Brad","Garret","Justin","John","Kevin"]

document.write(players.shuffle(200).join("<BR>") )
```

Obviously, at this time the print order is

```
NAME 
NAME
NAME
NAME
NAME
NAME
NAME
NAME
NAME
```

However I'd like it to be

```
NAME NAME
NAME NAME
NAME NAME
NAME NAME
NAME
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be more random after 200 shuffles than 1? Anyway, just shuffle however and group them at the end.

Comment: It makes it feel more random to me I suppose.  While it may not be more random, it doesn't affect loading speeds or anything so it's fine with me. I don't know if it's frowned upon in the community or not but it just feels more random.  Whatever...I always knew I was insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i=1; i<players.length+1; i+=2){
    console.log(players[i-1]+" "+((players[i]!=undefined)?players[i]:""));
}
```

or

```
for(var i=0; i<players.length; i+=2){
    console.log(players[i]+" "+((players[i+1]!=undefined)?players[i]:""));
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
Array.prototype.shuffle= function(times){
    var i,j,t,l=this.length;
    while(times--){
        with(Math){
            i=floor(random()*l);j=floor(random()*l);
        }
        t=this[i];this[i]=this[j];this[j]=t;
    }
    return this;
}

var players=["Ben","Caleb","Alex","Ryder","Brad","Garret","Justin","John","Kevin"]
players.shuffle(200);

for(var i=0; i<players.length; i+=2){
    document.write(players[i]+" "+((players[i+1]!=undefined)?players[i+1]:"")+"<br>");
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answering, however I'm confused as to how to implement it into your code?  Could you explain the placement of your supplied code to enable it to work?

Comment: Thanks again.
Implemented.

EDIT:  It seems to just be copying the first name like so:
   


           NAME1 NAME1
    NAME2 NAME2
    NAME3 NAME3
    NAME4 NAME4
    NAME5

Comment: Be careful with `players[i+1]!=undefined` since `0 == undefined` (the OP may use numbers instead of strings in future). Consider `i+1 in players` which is more precise and more is generally applicable.

Comment: @user2873801 woops, there was _?players[i]:"")_ instead of _?players[i+1]:"")_

Comment: @lancemanfv
I really do appreciate your help.
Thank you so much!

Comment: @RobG but `0 != undefined`

Comment: @lancemanfv—yeah, that one gets me often... both falsey but not equal. Though `null == undefined`. :-/ I just try to avoid those types of comparisions.

Comment: @RobG, ok, can you suggest an alternative that is more safe, by your opinion, to make sure that we won't print 'undefined' instead of array element in this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment:

*with* is greatly disliked and will be removed in a future version of ECMAScript. It's use here is entirely gratuitous, consider the equivalent:

```
    i = Math.random() * l | 0;
    j = Math.random() * l | 0;
```

In regard to printing out the members in twos, consider:

```
// Only increment by 1 in the condition
for(var i=0, iLen=players.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    // Second increment is in here
    console.log(players[i] + " " + (++i in players? players[i] : ''));
}
```

So if there are 3 items (i.e. items at index 0, 1 and 2) when it tests for `3 in players` it will return `false` and nothing is printed.

You could also do:

```
    console.log(players[i] + " " + (++i < iLen? players[i] : ''));
```

Comment: I will be sure to use this in the future, thank you for informing me.

Answer (score 0):

```
# first get your shuffled players
shuffled_players = players.shuffle(200)

# loop through them
for(var i=0; i<shuffled_players.length; i++){
  document.write(shuffled_players[i]);
  # put either a space or break
  document.write(i%2 == 0 ? " " : "<BR>");
}
```